# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes' when installing pip

Tags: pip, ctypes, python-3.7, failed-installation

On my RHEL 7.x system, I have system level python2.7 in /usr/bin and python3.7 in /usr/local/bin. I am trying to install pip for my python3.7 but I get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'" error. I did install libffi-devel but the issue still persists.

I installed libffi-devel using 
yum install libffi-devel
I have downloaded the get_pip file from here:
sudo wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
Now when I run 
sudo /usr/local/bin/python3.7 get-pip.py
I get the described error

Also, I tried 
sudo /usr/local/bin/python3.7 -m ensurepip
which gives me the same error.

How can I get pip installed successfully for my python3.7

Comment: Have you compiled Python yourself? Did you recompile after installing `libffi-devel`?

Comment: How can I do that? @phd

Comment: Same way as you have compiled it for the first time.

Comment: I removed the existing python3.7, installed and compiled it again , the issue is resolved. Thanks

Comment: I had this issue using python 3.7.5, the issue did not happen when I tried with python 3.7.1

Comment: after installing libffi-devel it still didn't worked for me. It turned out i need to uninstall python first (as it was installed prior libffi-devel installation) and then reinstall it (python) again - from then on everything\ worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Install the libffi development package:

```
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
```

and compile again.

Comment: And if you're on a shared host that doesn't have libffi-dev?

Comment: I don't know exactly, but I think you can install a new python On your side and working with that.

Comment: @hassanzadeh.sd After installing libffi, provide that package while recompiling the python libs ?